# Does Blindsight detect invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, invisibility, special-senses

Blindsight is described as using your other senses to detect your surroundings. Now, if someone invisible walked into my blindsight zone, would I be able to detect him, because he is only hidden from sight?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Yes.

PHB p. 291 description of the ***Invisible*** condition states in part:

> An invisible creature is impossible to see without the aid of magic or a special sense.

Blindsight is such a "special sense".  (Other special senses that work against invisible creatures are Tremorsense and Truesight.)

Comment: However, based on the same idea, is it safe to assume a perfectly silent creature would be invisible to Blindsight? (assuming it is not close enough to touch it)

Comment: @spectras One would reason they have to use hiding skills to remain hidden, despite being invisible. This is better off as a new question though for proper answers, not comments.

Comment: @spectras No, blindsight is not necessarily based on hearing the creature.  It may be based on echolocation or smell or even magic.

Comment: @Theik I would say you may be able to hide from a creature using echolocation (something large and solid between you and it) but not so easily in the case of something using heat or smell or other senses to locate the creature.  There may be ways to mask yourself from each of these types of sense, but you'd need to understand how the creature's blindsense works (which isn't necessarily specified in the MM, so you'd need to discuss with your DM)

Answer (score 9):

Blindsight is the use of a sense other than sight such as hearing(echolocation), touch(sensitivity to vibrations) to detect things within its radius. It can see anything that comes within its radius.

Tremorsense is a similar ability to Blindsight as well, but is limited to those who are touching the ground within a certain radius of the character.

All of the above forms of sight penetrate invisibility.