# Can you get an OA when blinded?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, vision-and-light, reactions, blind

If, for example, someone casts *Fog Cloud*, next to the *target A* and *target B* when they're fighting each other. If *target B* would run away from the fight he would cause an Opportunity Attack but when the area is Heavily obstructed (by the Fog Cloud spell) all the *targets* are counted as Blinded.

> **Blinded Condition**
>
> - A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails any ability check
>     that requires sight.
> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage,
>     and the creature’s Attack rolls have disadvantage

-

> **Opportunity Attack:**
>
> In a fight, everyone is constantly **watching** for a chance to strike an
>   enemy who is fleeing or passing by. Such a strike is called an
>   opportunity attack. You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile
>   creature that you can **see** moves out of your reach. To make the
>   opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack
>   against the provoking creature. The attack occurs right before the
>   creature leaves your reach.

If *target B* tries to leave *target A's* reach can *target A* use his Perception to beat *target B's* stealth? Or is *target B* is not detected, since *target B* cannot be seen? Or is *target B* forced to use Disengage even though he can't be seen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, an Opportunity Attack requires that one be able to **see** the target. While [other senses can count as "seeing" in some circumstances](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114074/when-an-invisible-character-leaves-a-blindsight-creatures-reach-does-the-creat), the rule is specific that it must be "a hostile creature that you can see", and that is what it means.